# How to generate automatically Makefile in vim (c/c++) super fast?

Tags: c++, c, vim, makefile, gnu-make

I'm quite new to vim,
have installed few plugins one of them is SnipMate,
which is quite useful while writing a short Makefile.

```
snippet base
    PHONY: clean, mrproper
    CC = gcc
    CFLAGS = -g -Wall

    all: $1

    %.o: %.c        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

    ${1:OUTPUT_FILENAME}: $1.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $+

    clean:      rm -f *.o core.*

    mrproper: clean         rm -f $1
```

but still it takes time to add manually the file names,
I'm quite sure with some **Vim Magic** :) , Vim would able to do it **automatically** (executing it via hotkey) after I have wrote those c files, any suggestions?

Thank you all!

Comment: You could head over to the vim stackexchange and ask there I guess for more chance of a good result.

Comment: @Hayt, I have to disagree. There are perfectly valid approaches which are 100% gnu-make if it's just about obtaining the unfiltered list of every C file in the directory. It would even be less cumbersome than an Vim approach that needs to be executed every time a file is added.

Comment: @LucHermitte yes there can be gnu-make approaches to do this. I was referring to have people make some "vim-magic" in general that stackexchange may result in more answers. Never said that this would be off-topic here.

Comment: @Hayt a few people and I answer vim questions on vi.SE and on SO. Regarding having quality answers, as long as some people close for "off-topic" or whatever reason, vim questions on SO get answers.

Comment: @LucHermitte yeah I just wanted to point out that it also exists as an alternative. ;) though still in beta.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract filenames automatically with `glob()`, and `globpath()` (don't ask me about SnipMate syntax to import the result -- I'm maintaining another template/snippet plugin).

But if you always use **everything** automatically, why don't you do it directly with make? There are ways to automatically glob filenames that match a pattern. If you need to trim files, well in that case listing explicitly every file you want to keep makes sense. But don't forget to remove unwanted files every time you trigger the *update the file list* action you wish to define.

BTW, IIRC, a properly configured gnumake (i.e, not mingw one) already has the rule for `%.o: %.c`